# Getting the correct spindle load call from the Okuma API

Tags: c#, api, okuma

I am trying to get the load for each spindle on a lathe.
Getting the axis loads works fine, but am not having luck with the spindle loads.
Before I work on subsystem calls want to make the first spindle work.
Below is what I have tried.

Axis load example (works fine):

```
private object zaxisload()
{
return objaxis.GetAxisLoad(AxisIndex2Enum.Z_Axis);
}
```

Attempt for spindle loads:

```
private object firstspindleload()
{
return objSpindle.GetSpindleLoad;
}
```

I have run the a program and the axis loads return a value, but the spindle load doesn't return any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't currently support reporting of sub-spindle load using API, but this will be implemented in the future. You can however get the load of the main spindle as a percentage. Perhaps you just forgot to define function?

```
Public Int GetSpindleLoad();  

Private object firstSpindleLoad()
{
return objSpindle.GetSpindleLoad;
}
```